# Box height in tabular

Tags: boxes, tabularx, dimensions

I have this macro `\code` that produces a box. And I want to create a tabular "environment" that acts like `enumerate` except it puts the items into a grid.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\def\code#1{\hbox{\vtop{\tt\def\\{\egroup\hbox\bgroup}\hbox\bgroup#1\egroup}}}

\def\twocolenum#1{{
  \newcounter{cnt}
  \setcounter{cnt}{0}
  \newbox{\cell}
  \newcolumntype{I}{>{\bgroup\setbox\cell=\hbox\bgroup}l<{\egroup\ifdim\wd\cell=0pt\else\stepcounter{cnt}\hskip1em\llap{(\alph{cnt})}\hskip1ex\usebox{\cell}\the\ht\cell\fi\egroup}}
  \begin{tabular}{II}
    #1
  \end{tabular}
}}

\begin{document}
\twocolenum{
  \multirow{2}{*}{\code{x = 0; \\ while (x >= 0) \{ \\ \ \ \ \ x++; \\ \}}} & bIt \\
      & cIt \\
  dIt & eIt \\
}
\end{document}
```

what I expected was a grid of `(a) (b) \\     (c) \\ (d) (e)`. That works, except for some reason the cell that contains `\code` appears to have height `0pt` and thus the code overlaps with the empty cell and the `d` cell. I know that all I am doing is hackish but can I somehow fix the behaviour to avoid the overlap?

Comment: Why don't you make a complete example instead of posting all this snippets?

Comment: With `\newcounter` and `\newbox` in the definition of `\twocolenum` you're looking for disgrace. What do you need a new box register for?

Comment: I know, this is just first attempt, but I am currently facing a completely different problem. the box is for saving the contents of the cell and analyzing them before shipping them out.

Comment: \multirow sets the dimension of its content to 0pt (so that it doesn't push the rows apart).

Comment: Yes, any way to overcome that and make it still make sense?